# Best strategy for custom profile properties in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I need to implement some (maybe 10) custom properties for logged in users for my MVC3 vb.net web app.
These will define how certain data is displayed within my views.

I can think of a couple of possible solutions..

1. Session variables. Will do the job but seems a bit untidy, and
   can't be strongly typed
2. custom properties of the current user object; is that even possible?
3. Custom profile provider. Looks like it might be a good option.

Has anyone got any tips on what worked well for them?

I already have custom membership and role providers that are working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First solution - use standard [ASP.NET Profile Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs) feature.

If for some reasons you can't use that - then I'd vote for custom profile provider.

Comment: The standard profiles properties aren't suitable as the values are in my own database. Any particular reason why you'd vote for custom profile provider - have you implemented one in mvc3?